# How to select context or scale on chart in chartjs quickchart io to run getValueForPixel?

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to run a function to create gradient line on my chart like:

y.getValueForPixel(50),

and for that I need chart pixel for a certain value, but I can't figure out to select it on quickchart, as context is undefined there.

On the front end I am doing it like this:

```
borderColor: function(context, options) { // context is automatically fetched here from chart
                let chart = context.chart;
                let {
                    ctx,
                    chartArea
                } = chart;
                if (!chartArea) {
                    return null;
                }
                return getGradient(ctx, chartArea, chart);
            }
```

getGradient function (for frontend):

```
 function getGradient(ctx, chartArea, chart) {
            let chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
            let chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
            if (gradient === null || width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
                width = chartWidth;
                height = chartHeight;
                let {
                    scales: {
                        x,
                        y
                    }
                } = chart;

                gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.top, 0, chartArea.bottom);
                
                gradient.addColorStop(0, 'green');

                gradient.addColorStop(y.getPixelForValue(50) / y.getPixelForValue(100), 'yellow')
            }
            return gradient;
        
        }`;
```

But I can't figure out how to select context on quickchart io, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The full chart context is unavailable in the Community version of QuickChart at this time for security reasons.  You'll either have to upgrade to [Professional](https://quickchart.io/pricing/) or [self-host](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart) the service.

However, there is a built-in function `getGradientFillHelper` that wraps some of this access and may achieve the desired effect.

Here's an exmaple:

```js
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [12, 6, 5, 18, 12, 20, 50, 80, 90],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: getGradientFillHelper('vertical', [
          '#eb3639',
          '#a336eb',
          '#36a2eb',
        ]),
        borderWidth: 5,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
}
```

[image: Chart.js on QuickChart with gradient line]

[Link to this chart in Quickchart editor](https://quickchart.io/sandbox/#%7B%22chart%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20type%3A%20%27line%27%2C%5Cn%20%20data%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B2012%2C%202013%2C%202014%2C%202015%2C%202016%2C%202017%2C%202018%2C%202019%2C%202020%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B12%2C%206%2C%205%2C%2018%2C%2012%2C%2020%2C%2050%2C%2080%2C%2090%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20false%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderColor%3A%20getGradientFillHelper(%27vertical%27%2C%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%23eb3639%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%23a336eb%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%2336a2eb%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D)%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderWidth%3A%205%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pointRadius%3A%200%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20options%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20legend%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22width%22%3A500%2C%22height%22%3A300%2C%22version%22%3A%222%22%2C%22backgroundColor%22%3A%22%23fff%22%7D)

[`getGradientFillHelper` documentation](https://quickchart.io/documentation/#colors-and-backgrounds)